# почему зависает nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, веб-сервер, nestjs

при локальной разработки все ок,
беру дроплет c такими параметрами
*1 GB Memory / 1 vCPU /25 GB Disk - Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64*

запускаю сервак на *nodejs* `npm run dev`
какое то время работает потом начинает виснуть , по ssh не подключится
но вот что странно - сервер что я запустил начинает бесконечно грузить страницу api но при этом nginx работает.
я пробывал разные команды такие как **pm2** и **screen** и разных поставщиков дроплетов, ни что не помогает если сервер дешевле чем 20$
в чем может быть причина ?

Comment: Возможно из-за запущенного mysql-server. По крайней мере у меня такое наблюдалось.
Попробуй узнать какой процесс грузит систему с помощью **htop**

Comment: 1 ГБ памяти явно мало, смотрите сколько ресурсов потребляет сервер

Comment: согласен что мало , но php+ nginx держится без проблем , а. что не так с нодой ?

Comment: Может и не с нодой, посмотрите в потреблении ресурсов